# Sublime text Color Highlighter enable circles before line number

Tags: sublimetext3

If you take a look at the first [example](https://github.com/Monnoroch/ColorHighlighter#colorhighlighter) on the plugin page you can see that all lines with color values in them have circles before the line number. I have been trying to figure out how can I enable theses circles for quite some time now. It is not mentioned in the official documentation and googling did not give me any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the page you linked to, in the installation section, it says:

> For gutter icons install [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).

ImageMagick provides the [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) utility, which the plugin uses to dynamically create the gutter icons.

When you install ImageMagick, make sure that it is added to your path. Otherwise, you can select **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> Color Highlighter -> Settings-Default`**, then open **`... -> Settings-User`** as well. Copy the contents of `Settings-Default` to `Settings-User`, then close Default. In User, look for the `"convert_util_path"` key, and set its value to the full path to `convert`. If you're on Windows, use forward slashes `/` as path delimiters instead of the standard back slashes `\`.

Comment: Apparently the answer was much more simple. I had to restart sublime in order to coloured circle to appear. Took me a while to figure out since I don't turn off my laptop